# $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-19})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have asked a similar question here before, which was about ring theory, but it is slightly different today and very trivial.

$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-19})$

Here, $\alpha$ is a root of $\alpha^2 - \alpha + 5$ and $\alpha^2 = \alpha - 5$, but I can't seem to understand this. Could anyone please explain how $\alpha$ is a root of $\alpha^2 - \alpha + 5$?

Comment: $2\alpha-1=\sqrt{-19}\Rightarrow (2\alpha-1)^2=-19\Rightarrow 4({\alpha}^2-\alpha+5)=0$.

Comment: abcd1234: Why not post the second question you added as a new question, in and of itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always *text* a proposed root by "plugging $\alpha$ in to $$\alpha^2 -\alpha + 5$$ and verifying that , in fact, the result evaluates to to zero.

But if you want to know how to *find* the roots of the quadratic, then put $\alpha^2 - \alpha + 5 = 0$ and solve for $\alpha$ using the quadratic formula:

$$\alpha = \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4(1)(5)}}2 =  \frac {1\pm \sqrt{-19}}2 =\frac{ 1\pm i\sqrt{19}}{2}$$

So each of $$\frac {1+i\sqrt{19}}2 \text{ and } \frac {1-i\sqrt{19}}2$$ are roots of the quadratic $f(\alpha) = \alpha^2 - \alpha + 5$.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for asking such an idiotic question here :)

Comment: No need to apologize!

Comment: @amWhy: I haven't found out if we should write $i$ in italic font or $\text{i}$ is the best way? The same is true for $exp(x)$ or $\text{exp}(x)$

Comment: Hi, @BabakS.!  I'm pretty sure we need $\exp(x)$ for $e^x$, and I think you can simply use `$i$` = $i$ (as it appears in dollar signs).  Also, Anytime your at MSE and want to chat or say hello, stop in at [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-criticism-and-constructive-praise), you can just ping me from there!

Comment: @amWhy: Yes I completely agree with you. That I m not there is my little Angel. She always hangs on me like a quala :-)

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha^2-\alpha+5=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{-19})^2-\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-19})+5=\frac{1}{4}(1+2\sqrt{-19}+(-19))-\frac{1}{4}(2+2\sqrt{-19})+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 20=\frac{1}{4}(1+2\sqrt{-19}+(-19)-2-2\sqrt{-19}+20)=0$